# UIImagePickerController not working iOS 9.3

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to access my photo library and camera using UIImagePickerController. However when i call `presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: false, completion: nil)` the app screen just freezes (it does not crash) and nothing happens, the UIImagePickerController is never shown nor the permission alert.

I've tried all solutions i've found available on internet, including adding **Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description** and changing the **Bundle Display Name** (some people have solved some permission issues using these solutions).

I also deleted the app and installed again and tried on different devices (and simulator), all present the same problem.

The same code works fine in iOS 9.2

Here's code i'm using:

```
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera) {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera;
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }

    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary) {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary;
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

I've implemented the delegate methods as well just in case.

Thank you guys!